# How to calculate the spherical integral?

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

I am trying very hard to to calculate an integral on a 2d disk $B(0,R)$, after I changed it to the spherical coordinate I do not know how to integrate it

$$\int_{\partial B(0,R)}\int_0^R\log \frac{|Re_1-rw|}{|Re_1-\frac{R^2w}{r}|}drdw$$ here the $|\cdot|$ denote the distance of the two vectors in Euclidean norm and $e_1=(1,0)'$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a potential problem involving image sources. Is there a physical-science application you have in mind?

Comment: @KBDave Yes, I am trying to integrate the Green's function in a 2d disk and I simplified it as the above.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality let $R=1$. Express $w$ in terms of the azimuth $\phi$: $w=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\ln\lvert e_1-rw\rvert&=\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(1-2r\cos\phi+r^2)\\
\ln\lvert e_1-w/r\rvert&=\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(1-2r^{-1}\cos\phi+r^{-2})=\ln\lvert e_1-rw\rvert-\ln r\\
\ln\frac{\lvert e_1-rw\rvert}{\lvert e_1-w/r\rvert}&=\ln r
\end{align}$$
so
$\int_0^1\ln\frac{\lvert e_1-rw\rvert}{\lvert e_1-w/r\rvert}\mathrm{d}r=\int_0^1\ln r\,\mathrm{d}r=\left.r(\ln r-1)\right\rvert_{0}^1=-1\text{.}$

Actually, we also know that

$$-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(1-2r\cos\phi+r^2)\mathrm{d}\phi=\begin{cases}0&r<1 \\ -\ln r & r>1\end{cases}\text{.}$$
People who study harmonic functions call this the [mean value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property), and people who study physics call this the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).